# CertVerifyProcBuiltin for accounts.google.com

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm facing an issue with Selenium that results in the following error during execution:

```
[120:2176:1208/224258.666:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(705)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for accounts.google.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[120:2176:1208/224258.722:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(705)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for clientservices.googleapis.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

[120:2176:1208/224258.753:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(705)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for www.google.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found
```

I've attempted to update Selenium and the WebDriver without success. Any suggestions on resolving this SSL certificate verification problem would be greatly appreciated.

Environment:

- Python
- Selenium 4.9.1
- undetected-chrome webdriver
- Operating System: Windows server 2019

Thanks